# How to check if a winforms control has been selected/toggled?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

How can I check if any control (check box/radio button) of the currently active form has been selected/toggled?

My goal is to create an option called **Save changes automatically** which would enable saving the current state of `check boxes` and `radio buttons`, so I need to know when any control is selected/toggled (to execute the save settings method). I don't want to create a separate event handler for every control, I'm looking for a generic solution if it is possible.

Comment: For a TextBox, detecting clicks won't be enough.

Comment: You are right, and I thought about that, but I am more concerned with check boxes and radio buttons. I can do with creating separate events for text fields.

Comment: you can create a method to save the state of any control and call this method from each control click event and pass the this control.

Comment: You're forgetting that a user could change something without clicking but focusing a control using tab.

Comment: @Fuex you are right. I think Ia ctually need to know when a controll has been toggled/selected.

Comment: If you really want it quick and dirty, look into the (Form) Validating event. But I won't post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a job for the user interface.

Use databinding to change a Model in code-behind and let the model trigger/escalate changes.

---

To help you on your way a little:

Your checkboxes and other controls are **not** where your data is. They should only show the data.

Create an object (the Model) with boolean properties for the checkboxes and int/enum properties for the radioboxes. Set up the databindings from the controls to the properties.

Then you can implement the necessary logic in the Setters of the properties.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what that means. I will have to do some research in regard to your answer.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, good answer, even if the OP doesn't understand it. Maybe some extra info on how to accomplish this is necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Henk. I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 0):

As Henk proposed, you could use a [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) pattern such as MVC to separate UI and domain logic. As the user makes changes to some UI widget, you update the value in the model, for example by setting a property. The property setters could then update a `IsDirty` (or HasChanges, ...) field. This property would be read by the UI which would, depending on the value of IsDirty, decide what needs to be done. (Display a MessageBox("Do you want to save your changes") or something else)

I do think that Henk was thinking web while you tagged the question with `WinForms`. Chances are you are not using a pattern to separate UI and domain logic. (and that UI and domain code are already so intertwined that your current deadline does not allow you to introduce a model right now)

You could achieve the same thing by placing the IsDirty field on your `Form` and having the `Changed EventHandlers` set that IsDirty value. By subclassing the Form (ie put the IsDirty on your 'FormBase') and your controls (for example by introducing a watermark), you could have this behavior out of the box for all your forms.